# Scala: Read and filter lines

Tags: scala, function, filter

I am currently working on a Scala project. As the first time trying to deal with a program in this kind of difficulty, I am extremely lost and frustrated right now.

In this project I am supposed to:

1. read a txt file called [*map.txt*](https://drive.google.com/a/trinity.edu/file/d/0By586JlA3J5_WmlROE1iSkJsRDg/view?usp=sharing), which contains lots of
   information of several rooms
2. store specific lines (parts) as different elements of two
   Arrays(rooms & actions), which consists of two defined classes.

The meaning of the lines in the file :

- **3** in the first line is the total number of the rooms
- **0** in the second line is the room_number of the first room
- **Halsell 228** is the room_name of the first room
- **paragraph** is the description of the first room
- **1** in the forth line is the number of different directions that user can choose to go. In here is 1 because user in the first room can only choose to go toward east
- **east** on the fifth lines is the direction option that user can choose to go
- **1** besides east is the room_number of the destination room of choosing go towards east
- Then room 1 so on so forth ...

So basically in this *map.txt*, I have 3 rooms: Halsell 228(room 1), Halsell 2nd Hallway(room 2), CS Office(room 3)

I think I have to utilize two functions to filter or take out the parts of lines that I want to save. But I really don't know how to do it. This is what I've come up so far:

```
import io.Source

case class Action(direc: String, dest: Int)
case class Room(roomNumber: Int, roomName: String, desc: String, array: Array[Action])

val source = Source.fromFile("map.txt")
val lines = source.getLines

def parseLineR(line: String):Room = {
  // apparently IDK anything...
  Room(parts(0).toInt, parts(1),parts(2),parts(3))        
}

def parseLineD(line: String):Action = {
  // really don't know
  Action(parts(0),parts(1).toInt)                        
}

val room =      
val actions = 

source.close
```

I want to create two arrays, which may look like these:

```
val rooms = Array(Room(0,"sa","sb",actions),Room(1,"ww","wa",actions),...)
val actions = Array(Action("east", 0), Action("west", 1),...)
```

And the numbers of the elements in each array should depend on

1. in rooms: are the numbers of total rooms and
2. in actions: are the numbers of total direction options.

Comment: We cannot view the file without asking for permission.

Comment: Could be that one:
http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~mlewis/CSCI1320-F12/Code/map.txt

Comment: 1. Specify the file format. Your approach is not going to work, as room informations and directions are spread over multiple lines. 2. What will your final data structure look like. How do you retrieve directions for rooms? Or are these number indeces?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that there are dependencies and a strict order between lines. Source is probably the wrong class to use here, as it basically assumes you will read several identically formatted chunks. Instead, use a [Java Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (which you can use from Scala with no issues).

Scanner allows you to get one thing at a time, so you can do something like this:

```
case class Action(direc:String, dest:Int)
case class Room(number:Int, name:String, desc:String, array:Seq[Action])

val sc = new java.util.Scanner(new File("map.txt"))

def readAction() = Action(sc.next(), sc.nextInt())

def readRoom() = Room(
  sc.nextInt(),
  sc.nextLine(),
  sc.nextLine(),
  for(i <- 1 to sc.nextInt()) yield readAction()
)

val roomCount = sc.nextInt()
val rooms = for(i <- 1 to roomCount) yield readRoom()
println(rooms)
sc.close()
```

This prints:

```
Vector(
  Room(
    0, 
    Halsell 228,    
    You are standing in a room full of computers and comfy chairs with a giant air conditioning unit hanging from the ceiling.  While the surroundings are serine enough, you can't help feeling a certain amount of dread. This isn't just a fear that the air conditioning unit is going to fall either. Something in you tells you that this room is regularly used for strange rituals involving torture. You can only wonder what happens here and why there isn't blood all over the place. Your uneasyness makes you want to leave quickly.,Vector(Action(east,1))), Room(1, Halsell 2nd Hallway,    This is a long dark hallway with rough carpet and multiple doors leading out.  The dispair of lost souls hangs heavily in the air.,
    Vector(
        Action(west,0), 
        Action(east,2)
    )
  ), 
  Room(
     2, 
     CS Office, 
     You stand in the main office of the Computer Science Department at Trinity University.  An overwhelming evil fills the room.  It appears to come from one of the many side offices.  Looking at the door you see it says 201K.  You feel an overwhelming desire to flee this place before work is heaped upon you.,
     Vector(
       Action(west,1)
     )
   )
 )
```

(indentation mine)

Note that the order in which you read from the file matters. If you say, change the order of attributes in the constructors you will need some intermediate variables.

Comment: Note that this solution fails for this input http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~mlewis/CSCI1320-F12/Code/map.txt

Comment: Sorry. Used the wrong Scanner constructor that uses the parameter as the input. Fixed by adding `new File("map.txt")` instead of `"map.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using tail recursion, pattern maching and avoiding mutability:

```
import io.Source

case class Action(direc:String, dest:Int)
object Action {
  /* Just a helper method, not a big deal */
  def apply(line: String): Action = {
    val columns = line.split(" ")
    Action(columns(0), columns(1).toInt)
  }
}

case class Room(roomNumber: Int, roomName: String, 
                desc: String, array: List[Action])

val source = Source.fromFile("map.txt")
val lines = source.getLines

def isNumber(line: String) = line.forall(_.isDigit)
def isNotNumber(line: String) = ! isNumber(line)

def parseLines(lines: Seq[String], rs: List[Room]): List[Room] = lines match {
  case head :: tail if head.forall(_.isSpaceChar) =>
    parseLines(tail, rs) // discard empty lines
  case head :: tail =>
    val roomLines = head :: tail.takeWhile(isNotNumber)
    val otherLines = tail.dropWhile(isNotNumber)
    val newBaseRoom = Room(head.toInt, "", "", List[Action]())
    val newRoom = roomLines.foldLeft(newBaseRoom)(parseRoomLine)
    parseLines(otherLines, rs :+ newRoom)
  case Nil => rs
}

def parseRoomLine(r: Room, iline: String): Room = iline match {
  case line if line.forall(_.isDigit) => r.copy(roomNumber = line.toInt)
  case line if line.head.isDigit =>
    r.copy(roomName = line)
  case text if text.startsWith("east") || text.startsWith("west") =>
    r.copy(array = r.array :+ Action(text))
  case text => r.copy(desc = text)
}

val rooms = parseLines(lines.toList, List())
rooms.foreach(println)

source.close
```